# Ajax request data could not show into the input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have created a loop which contains a dropdown list and input field.
What I need is:
When I select a value from dropdown list of Fruit Genres, the Unit Price field will display value come from database. I did all of these, but could not display value to the Unit Price field.

Here is my code:

View page:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover" id="item-tbl">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">Fruit Type</th>
        <th class="text-center">Fruit Genres</th>
        <th class="text-center">Qty</th>
        <th class="text-center">Unit Price</th>
        <th class="text-center">Sub Total</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){ ?>
    <tr style="">
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('fruit_type_id', ['options'=>$fruit_types, 'empty'=>'Select Fruit Type', 'label'=>false, 'name'=>'detail_orders['.$i.'][fruit_type_id]']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('fruit_genre_id', ['options'=>$fruit_genres, 'empty'=>'Select Fruit Genre', 'label'=>false, 'name'=>'detail_orders['.$i.'][fruit_genre_id]', 'class'=>'fruit_genre']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('quantity', ['type'=>'text', 'label'=>false, 'name'=>'detail_orders['.$i.'][quantity]', 'class'=>'quantity', 'id'=>'quantity_'.$i]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('price', ['type'=>'text', 'label'=>false, 'name'=>'detail_orders['.$i.'][price]', 'class'=>'price', 'id'=>'price_'.$i]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('sub_total', ['type'=>'text', 'label'=>false, 'name'=>'detail_orders['.$i.'][price]', 'class'=>'sub_total']); ?></td>
    </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fruit_genre").on('change' , function() {
        var fruitGenreId = +$(this).val();
        var priceId = $(this).closest('tr').find('.price').attr('id');
        // alert(priceId);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: baseURL+"orders/getFruitById/"+fruitGenreId+".json",
            beforeSend: false,
            success : function(returnData) {
                if(returnData.response.code == '200'){
                    console.log(returnData.response.data.unit_price);
                   // $(this).closest('tr').find('.price').val(returnData.response.data.unit_price);
                    $(priceId).val(returnData.response.data.unit_price);
                };
            }
        })
    }).trigger('change');        
});
```

OrdersController.php

```
public function getFruitById($id){
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('ajax');

    $this->loadModel('FruitGenres');
    $item = $this->FruitGenres->get($id);

    if (!empty($item)) {
        $response['code'] = 200;
        $response['message'] = 'DATA_FOUND';
        $response['data'] = $item;
    }else{
        $response['code'] = 404;
        $response['message'] = 'DATA_NOT_FOUND';
        $response['data'] = array();
    }


    $this->set('response', $response);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['response']);
}
```

I have got the expected data to the javascript console. but could not pass the data to the input field.

I have tried:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.price').val(returnData.response.data.unit_price);
```

instead of

```
$(priceId).val(returnData.response.data.unit_price);
```

into the ajax success function, but it did not worked.

if I add a static id like the following:

```
$('#price_1').val(returnData.response.data.unit_price);
```

then it works.

Can anyone please help me? I am stuck on it.

I am using cakephp 3 for my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`priceId` is a value like `price_1` without `#`. To make it a selector by id - prepend it with `#`:

```
$("#" + priceId).val(returnData.response.data.unit_price);
```

You can even simplify your code:

```
// you get id of the found element so as to find this element again
// you can store founded element instead of it's id
var priceDiv = $(this).closest('tr').find('.price');

// in success callback:
priceDiv.val(returnData.response.data.unit_price);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the element directly instead of getting its ID and select with another jQuery call.

Another thing to note - `this` in the submit callback refer to the callback function itself, not the element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fruit_genre").on('change' , function() {
        var fruitGenreId = +$(this).val();

        var $price = $(this).closest('tr').find('input.price'); // Get the element

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: baseURL+"orders/getFruitById/"+fruitGenreId+".json",
            beforeSend: false,
            success : function(returnData) {
                if(returnData.response.code == '200'){
                    console.log(returnData.response.data.unit_price);

                    // Use $price directly as a jQuery object
                    $price.val(returnData.response.data.unit_price);
                };
            }
        })
    }).trigger('change');        
});
```